# Using RMI in GWT Application

Tags: java, gwt, rmi

I have a GWT application, and I was wondering if I can use RMI in my GWT app; or if i can make my GWT app have two different servers.

Thanks!

Comment: rmi: at serverside yes, at clienttside not

Comment: whaat do you mean with "two different server"?

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: What I mean by two servers is that I want my client to interact with two different servers(one is the web server (do the web stuff), and the other one is remote server( to do client server stuff ). I hope I am clear.

Comment: EJP, I am asking because I tried but I got errors... So I was not sure if it can be done.

Comment: Why not ask about the errors?

Answer (score 2):

Just make your gwt servlet the client of the RMI server, and let the client talk to the servlet.

Find the RMI server at the init of your servlet and then direct all the calls there.

```
String bindName = _rmiAddress + "/" + SERVER_NAME;
_server = (ServiceServerRMI) Naming.lookup(bindName);
```